# Only one character returned from PyUnicode_AsWideCharString

Tags: python, c++, python-c-api

I'm trying to get in a Visual Studio 2012 C++ program the value of a string variable defined in a embedded Python environment using Python's C API.

As embedded environment, I'm using Python 3.4.3 64-bit, which I downloaded from https://www.python.org/downloads/

This is the code I'm using in Visual Studio 2012 (target: Release, x64):

```
#include <Python.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

  Py_Initialize();

  PyObject *main = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
  PyObject *globals = PyModule_GetDict(main);
  PyRun_SimpleString("my_var = 'Hello, World!'; print('Value of my_var in Python: ' +  my_var)");

  PyObject* value = PyDict_GetItemString(globals, "my_var");
  wchar_t* fetched_value = PyUnicode_AsWideCharString(value, NULL);
  Py_DECREF(value);

  wchar_t result[20];
  wcscpy_s(result, 19, fetched_value);
  PyMem_Free(fetched_value);

  printf("Value of my_var in C: %s", result);

  Py_Finalize();

  return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, I get this output:

```
Value of my_var in Python: Hello, World!
Value of my_var in C: H
```

Why am I getting only the first character of `Hello, World!` in my call to `PyUnicode_AsWideCharString(value, NULL);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%s` format specifier denotes a narrow string (`char*`). You want `%ls`, which denotes a wide string (`wchar_t*`):

```
printf("Value of my_var in C: %ls", result);
```

You should also be preferring `wprintf`; it's not a good idea to mix narrow and wide strings, as you're doing here.

Comment: Ops! Thank you, I was really looking at the wrong place.